# ASP.Net MVC : Bind drop down list with nested list type collection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, webgrid, dropdownlistfor

I am showing student data in webgrid. I am showing student id, first name, last name, state and city. the way I am working now I am getting data. I am doing webgrid in line edit which is working. the moment I click on edit button then textbox and dropdown is coming properly on grid cell. now state and city dropdown is coming. the way I code it now state is showing all state and city also showing all city but I want state dropdown should show all state but city dropdown should show only those city based on student state id.

now in my view model state and city list type property getting load independently but I want to bit redesign the code. I want to load all state but in case of city I want to load it based on student state id.

### now my preset view model look like

```
public class StudentListViewModel
{
    public int StartIndex { get; set; }
    public int EndIndex { get; set; }
    public int page { get; set; }
    public int RowCount { get; set; }
    public int PageSize { get; set; }
    public int CurrentPage { get; set; }

    public string sort { get; set; }
    public string sortdir { get; set; }

    public IList<Student> Students { get; set; }

    public int SelectedStateId { set; get; }
    public IList<State> States { get; set; }

    public int SelectedCityId { set; get; }
    public IList<City> Cities { get; set; }

    public StudentListViewModel()
    {
        PageSize = 5;
        sort = "ID";
        sortdir = "ASC";
        CurrentPage = 1;
    }

    public void SetUpParams(StudentListViewModel oSVm)
    {
        if (oSVm.page == 0)
            oSVm.page = 1;

        StartIndex = ((oSVm.page * oSVm.PageSize) - oSVm.PageSize) + 1;
        EndIndex = (oSVm.page * oSVm.PageSize);
        CurrentPage = (StartIndex - 1) / oSVm.PageSize;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(oSVm.sort))
            oSVm.sort = "ID";

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(oSVm.sortdir))
            oSVm.sortdir = "ASC";
    }
}
```

### Model classes

```
   public class Student
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
        public int StateID { get; set; }
        public string StateName { get; set; }
        public int CityID { get; set; }
        public string CityName { get; set; }
    }

        public class State
        {
            public int ID { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }

    public class City
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

Student controller
---------------------
  public class StudentController : Controller
    {
        private StudentRepository _Studentdata;
        private StateRepository _Statedata;
        private CityRepository _Citydata;

        public StudentController()
        {

            _Studentdata = new StudentRepository(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["StudentDBContext"].ConnectionString);
            _Statedata = new StateRepository(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["StudentDBContext"].ConnectionString);
            _Citydata = new CityRepository(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["StudentDBContext"].ConnectionString);
        }

        // GET: Stuent
        public ActionResult List(StudentListViewModel oSVm)
        {
            if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000); // just simulate delay of one second

            StudentListViewModel SVm = new StudentListViewModel();
            SVm.SetUpParams(oSVm);
            SVm.Students = _Studentdata.GetStudents(oSVm.page, oSVm.PageSize, oSVm.sort, oSVm.sortdir).ToList(); // populating student
            SVm.States = _Statedata.GetAll().ToList(); // populating state
            SVm.Cities = _Citydata.GetAll().ToList(); // populating city
            SVm.RowCount = _Studentdata.DataCounter;
            return View("ListStudents",SVm);
        }

}
```

### this is my webgrid code

```
@{
    WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(null, rowsPerPage: Model.PageSize, canPage: true,
        defaultSort: Model.sort, ajaxUpdateContainerId: "gridContent", ajaxUpdateCallback: "initScripts");
    grid.Bind(Model.Students, autoSortAndPage: false, rowCount: Model.RowCount);
    grid.PageIndex = Model.CurrentPage;
}


@grid.GetHtml(
        tableStyle: "webgrid-table",
        headerStyle: "webgrid-header",
        footerStyle: "webgrid-footer",
        alternatingRowStyle: "webgrid-alternating-row",
        selectedRowStyle: "webgrid-selected-row",
        rowStyle: "webgrid-row-style",
        mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
        firstText: "<<",
        previousText: "<",
        nextText: ">",
        lastText: ">>",
        numericLinksCount: 5,
        columns:
            grid.Columns
            (
            grid.Column(columnName: "ID", header: "ID", format: @<text>@item.ID <input type="hidden" name="HiddenID" value="@item.ID" id="HiddenID"  /></text>,style:"SmallCols"),
            grid.Column(columnName: "FirstName", header: "First Name", format: @<text><span class="display-mode">@item.FirstName</span><input type="text" id="txtFirstName" value="@item.FirstName" class="edit-mode" /></text>,style:"NameColWidth" ),
            grid.Column(columnName: "LastName", header: "Last Name", format: @<text><span class="display-mode">@item.LastName</span><input type="text" id="txtLastName" value="@item.LastName" class="edit-mode" /></text>,style:"NameColWidth"),

            grid.Column(columnName: "StateName", header: "State Name", format: @<text><span class="display-mode">@item.StateName</span>@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedStateId, new SelectList(Model.States, "ID", "Name", Model.SelectedStateId= item.StateID), "-- Select States--", new { id = "cboState", @class = "edit-mode" })</text>,style:"NameColWidth"),
            grid.Column(columnName: "CityName", header: "City Name", format: @<text><span class="display-mode">@item.CityName</span>@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedCityId, new SelectList(Model.Cities, "ID", "Name", Model.SelectedCityId = item.CityID), "-- Select City--", new { id = "cboCity", @class = "edit-mode" })
</text>,style:"NameColWidth"),
            grid.Column(header: "IsActive",
            format: @<text><input id="select" class="box" name="select"
                                  type="checkbox" @(item.IsActive ? "checked='checked'" : "") value="@item.IsActive" /></text>
                    , style: "text-center checkbox-width SmallCols"),

             grid.Column("Action", format: @<text>
                        <button class="edit-user display-mode btnGreen">Edit</button>
                        <button class="edit-user display-mode btnRed">Delete</button>
                        <button class="save-user edit-mode btnGreen">Save</button>
                        <button class="cancel-user edit-mode btnSky">Cancel</button>
            </text>, style: "ActionCol", canSort: false)

                        ))
```

I can put this property `public IList<City> Cities { get; set; }` from view model to student class but the problem is I do not know how to refer nested list type property in dropdown

this way can my dropdown point to nested `Cities` property ?

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedCityId, new SelectList(Model.Cities, "ID", "Name", Model.SelectedCityId = item.CityID), "-- Select City--", new { id = "cboCity", @class = "edit-mode" })

how to refer this line Model.Students.Cities i mean
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedCityId, new SelectList(Model.Students.Cities, "ID", "Name", Model.SelectedCityId = item.CityID), "-- Select City--", new { id = "cboCity", @class = "edit-mode" })
```

I tried `Model.Students.Cities` but city property is not coming!

where I am making the mistake? looking for guidance and suggestion. thanks

Comment: its early in the morning for me but i can not see Cities linked to Students... anywhere.... maybe that's what you need to look at?

Comment: I mean your model classes... do these represent entities? if so then you need to building some sort of foreign key... to have the relationship you are wanting.

Comment: anyone can come down with some sample code just to have idea how to accomplish it.

Comment: suppose in webform if i need to show student data in gridview then we can bound gridview with student data and gridview 
has rowdata bound event from that event we can populate state data in state dropdown in each gridview row and same
way we can populate city data in city drop down but when we load city data then we can pass student stateid and as a 
result in each row only few city data will be populated in dropdown as per student state id.

the same i want to achieve in MVC with webgrid. now see my code and tell what to change in my
code to achieve it. thanks